# How to find velocity and acceleration as instantaneous rate of change of a position function?

Tags: calculus

I'm self-studying Calc 1 for Engineers, and here's the question:

Suppose a particle is moving along a straight line and its position with respect to a reference point is $s=4\cdot t^3-8\cdot t^2+3\cdot t+2$, where $s$ is in meters and $t$ is in seconds.

A) Find the velocity and acceleration as functions of $t$.

B) Find the acceleration after 1 second.

C) Find the acceleration at the instance(s) when the velocity is 0.

I'm not sure how to define velocity and acceleration as functions in this context, though. Previously, in Physics, I was taught that velocity is distance divided by time; however, since we're dealing with rate of change, I assume the process is different. I tried researching the equations to use, but results varied: some suggested I take the limit of the function, others simply just repeated the distance/time thing, etc. I'm just not sure where to start. Parts B and C should be self-explanatory once I can figure out part A, though; B is just substitution, and C refers to points of inflection (I assume).

I saw another thread on here referring to a similar question, and perhaps I misunderstood the answers, but it also sounded like velocity is just the derivative of the function, and acceleration is the derivative of velocity.

Comment: The formula of (for example) velocity equaling distance divided by time is really only useful under the assumption of constant velocity.  Your alternate view, that velocity and acceleration represent the first and second derivatives of the distance $~\color{red}{\text{as a function of time}}$ are applicable.

Comment: One possible point of confusion is that the posting gives **position** as a function of time.  You then have to construe *distance traveled* as being represented by position.  What this means is that if you have a position function where sometimes the position is decreasing, this implies that sometimes the velocity is negative. ...see next comment

Comment: This can be confusing, because a non-Mathematician might reasonably feel that even when the position is decreasing, the distance traveled (*along the route*) is still increasing.  This then becomes an issue of how you **arbitrarily** define distance traveled.

Comment: @user2661923 I think I see what you're saying. So, represented as a function of time, assuming I'm on the right track with the derivatives thing, the second derivative, acceleration (for example) as a function of time would be 24t-16? Since we're still (at this point in the problem) trying to solve for t? I hope I'm at least getting warmer to the right idea lol

Comment: Yes, the acceleration is $24t - 16$.

Comment: @user2661923 Sweet! Thank you so much! :) I'd like to eventually minor in mathematics so I'm just trying to make sure I have the essential knowledge on lock before I jump into more complex stuff.

Comment: Position is a measure of *displacement*, the signed distance from the initial position.